# Hi guys, I want to implement logs to my passed test case in extend reports and screenshot of failed test case

Tags: selenium, logging, appium, screenshot, extentreports

Thats my extent manger class where I have implemented extents reports and  version is 3.1.5

```
package resources;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.SkipException;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.aventstack.extentreports.AnalysisStrategy;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.Status;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.markuputils.ExtentColor;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.markuputils.MarkupHelper;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentHtmlReporter;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.configuration.ChartLocation;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.configuration.Theme;


import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.AndroidMobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class ExtentManager {

     private static ExtentReports extent;
        private static Platform platform;
        private static String reportFileName = "ExtentReports-Version3-Test-Automaton-Report.html";
        private static String macPath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "/TestReport";
        private static String windowsPath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "\\TestReport";
        private static String macReportFileLoc = macPath + "/" + reportFileName;
        private static String winReportFileLoc = windowsPath + "\\" + reportFileName;

        public static ExtentReports getInstance() {
            if (extent == null)
                createInstance();
            return extent;
        }

        //Create an extent report instance
        public static ExtentReports createInstance() {
            platform = getCurrentPlatform();
            String fileName = getReportFileLocation(platform);
            ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(fileName);
            htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.BOTTOM);
            htmlReporter.config().setChartVisibilityOnOpen(true);
            htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);
            htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle(fileName);
            htmlReporter.config().setEncoding("utf-8");
            htmlReporter.config().setReportName(fileName);

            extent = new ExtentReports();
            extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);

            return extent;
        }

        //Select the extent report file location based on platform
        private static String getReportFileLocation (Platform platform) {
            String reportFileLocation = null;
            switch (platform) {
                case MAC:
                    reportFileLocation = macReportFileLoc;
                    createReportPath(macPath);
                    System.out.println("ExtentReport Path for MAC: " + macPath + "\n");
                    break;
                case WINDOWS:
                    reportFileLocation = winReportFileLoc;
                    createReportPath(windowsPath);
                    System.out.println("ExtentReport Path for WINDOWS: " + windowsPath + "\n");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("ExtentReport path has not been set! There is a problem!\n");
                    break;
            }
            return reportFileLocation;
        }

        //Create the report path if it does not exist
        private static void createReportPath (String path) {
            File testDirectory = new File(path);
            if (!testDirectory.exists()) {
                if (testDirectory.mkdir()) {
                    System.out.println("Directory: " + path + " is created!" );
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Failed to create directory: " + path);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Directory already exists: " + path);
            }
        }

        //Get current platform
        private static Platform getCurrentPlatform () {
            if (platform == null) {
                String operSys = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
                if (operSys.contains("win")) {
                    platform = Platform.WINDOWS;
                } else if (operSys.contains("nix") || operSys.contains("nux")
                        || operSys.contains("aix")) {
                    platform = Platform.LINUX;
                } else if (operSys.contains("mac")) {
                    platform = Platform.MAC;
                }
            }
            return platform;
        }
    }
```

and my test listener class code is

```
package resources;

import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;

public class TestListener implements ITestListener {
     //Extent Report Declarations
    private static ExtentReports extent = ExtentManager.createInstance();
    private static ThreadLocal<ExtentTest> test = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @Override
    public synchronized void onStart(ITestContext context) {
        System.out.println("Extent Reports Version 3 Test Suite started!");
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
        System.out.println(("Extent Reports Version 3  Test Suite is ending!"));
        extent.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println((result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " started!"));
        ExtentTest extentTest = extent.createTest(result.getMethod().getMethodName(),result.getMethod().getDescription());
        test.set(extentTest);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println((result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " passed!"));
        test.get().pass("Test passed");
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println((result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " failed!"));
        test.get().fail(result.getThrowable());
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println((result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " skipped!"));
        test.get().skip(result.getThrowable());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println(("onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage for " + result.getMethod().getMethodName()));
    }
}
```

and my logger file is

```
 package logger;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.FileAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout;

/**
 * contains all the methods to show the logs on console 
 * and save the logs in LogFile.txt of each run.

 */
public class Log
{

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("logger");
    private static PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout("%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1} - %m%n");
    private static FileAppender appender;
    private static ConsoleAppender consoleAppender;

    static
    {
        try 
        {
            consoleAppender = new ConsoleAppender(layout, "System.out");
            appender= new FileAppender(layout,"LogFile.txt",true);
        }
        catch (IOException exception) 
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * method to display errors in log.
     * @param className name of class in which error occurred.
     * @param methodName name of method in which error occurred.
     * @param exception stack trace of exception
     */
    public static void logError (String className,String methodName,String exception) 
    {   
        LOGGER.addAppender(appender);
        LOGGER.setLevel((Level) Level.INFO);
        LOGGER.info("ClassName :"+className);
        LOGGER.info("MethodName :"+methodName );
        LOGGER.info("Exception :" +exception);
        LOGGER.info("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    }

    /**
     * method to display information in logs
     * @param message message to be displayed
     */
    public static void info(String message){
        consoleAppender.setName("Console");
        LOGGER.addAppender(consoleAppender);
        LOGGER.addAppender(appender);
        LOGGER.setLevel((Level) Level.INFO);
        LOGGER.info(message);
    }

}
```

I want to make changes in extents reports so that logs should be displayed in extents report when the test case got pass and want to add screenshot for the failed test cases in extents reports please suggest where I have to make changes.Above both code are working properly.

Comment: Log.info("test");
if you want to logs in test case

Answer (score 0):

To Add screenshot for failed tests in Extent Reports, Use the below code :

```
@Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        test.get().fail("Test Failed"+result.getThrowable());
        WebDriver driver = null;

        Object testObj = result.getInstance(); //Instance of test failed
        Class testClass = result.getTestClass().getRealClass(); //Class in which test failed


        try {
            Field driverField = testClass.getDeclaredField("driver"); //get the driver field of failed test class
            driverField.setAccessible(true); // if driver field is private
            driver = (WebDriver)driverField.get(testObj); // here you get the driver of failed test method

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        try {
            test.get().addScreenCaptureFromPath(TestUtil.getScreenshotPath(driver, result.getMethod().getMethodName()), result.getMethod().getMethodName()); // this method will add the screenshot for failed test in extent report
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Note: Here TestUtil is the utility class where getScreenshotPath method is present. Call that method which should return the path of failed screenshot in your project. Code for that is below:

```
public static String getScreenshotPath(WebDriver driver, String testcaseName) throws IOException {

    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    String destPath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "\\screenshots\\" + testcaseName +System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
    File destFile= new File(destPath);
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, destFile);
    return destPath;
}
```

Hope it helps :)